# Use wirecast and obs at the same time

Tags: video-recording, obs

I am new to video production and I would like to ask you if is it possible to use OBS and Wirecast at the same time. Is there a possibility of conflict or something? In my case, I have a Blackmagic Intensity Pro 4K installed and I want to use Wirecast for recording and OBS for streaming (one source/video camera), but although I see my source video at Wirecast, I cant see it at OBS. 
Thanks in advance.

p.s. I know both programs support streaming and recording but I need to use both at the same time.